# The spring boot project cannot access static files

Tags: html, spring-boot, vue.js

I created a new springboot project, the directory structure of the project is as follows：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wTtj.png)
The yml configuration is as follows:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8783
  servlet:
    context-path: /spring-demo

spring:
  scan : com.example
  application:
    name: spring-demo
  mvc:
    view:
      suffix: .html
      prefix: /
  web:
    resources:
      static-path-pattern: /**
      static-locations: classpath:/templates/,classpath:/static/
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
    suffix: .html
```

`IndexController` is as follows

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(){
        System.out.println("index");
        return "/index";
    }
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">
  <title>private-report</title>
</head>

<body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but private-report doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable
  it to continue.</strong></noscript>
<div id="app"></div>
<link href="/static/js/chunk-vendors.365b8cfb.js" rel="preload" as="script">

</body>

</html>
```

When I start the spring-demo service and enter http://localhost:8783/spring-demo/index in the browser, the page reports an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db7QM.png)

The index interface can be accessed, but the js file cannot be accessed and a 404 error is reported.

I tried many ways but couldn't access the js file, and the spring boot version is `2.5.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found your error. You use the root context path `spring-demo` which is not applied to the relative path as needed

You must change it into

```
   <link href="/spring-demo/static/js/chunk-vendors.365b8cfb.js" rel="preload" as="script">
```

Comment: This still doesn't work，this link http://localhost:8783/js/chunk-vendors.365b8cfb.js still reports a 404 error!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. According to your suggestion, the js file is now accessible!